# Layouts in Android SDK

Tags: android, xml, layout

Is there a way to load an XML Layout without the R class?
And if possible to load it from a string?

Comment: how you will call that string? without R...?

Comment: look this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5325002/1012284

Comment: Why are you bothered about not using R class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, eg if you want to load a xml from the web and inflate it to ViewGroup.

Use `(LayoutInflater) mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);`

and inflate from a xml:

```
mInflater.inflate(XmlPullParser parser, ViewGroup root)
```

you will be able to load the xml from the web by performing a webrequest and use the DocumentBuilder

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db;
try {
 db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
 Document doc =  db.parse([INPUT_STREAM]);
 ....
```