# Android - Change activity contentview in runtime

Tags: android, xml, server, runtime

I'm developing a generic Android application that needs to get XML files from the server and set its contentview accordingly.

The XML files can be as simple as a relative layout with a textview or much more complex, that's really not relevant. The goal is to simply fetch XML files externally and display them **or** receive a string from the server, create a XML file locally on runtime and use it, both will do.

I've been looking for a while now and I didn't find any solution. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325002/activities-loading-xml-layout-dynamically-in-android) which references Android's [LayoutInflater doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html); it is not possible since there's some "pre-processing of XML files that is done at build time."

In short, you can't use a regular xml pulled externally to inflate.