# Setting a shape drawable as background programmatically without a drawable reference

Tags: android, drawable, android-drawable, android-resources

Using a drawable reference to `myshape.xml` I can set a background like this:

```
v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myshape);
```

But what if I want/need to set it all programatically **without** using **drawable** reference? Is it possible somehow to supply the `<shape/>` as a string to set such background without a need of the external resource file `drawable\myshape.xml`?

Comment: It is not possible to write the xml of layouts at runtime. So I think that it is not possible to write any custom xml. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325002/activities-loading-xml-layout-dynamically-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background using a drawable, via the call to `v.setBackground()` function. 
The question should have been, can you create a shape drawable programatically, not via resource. 
You can create some shapes programatically, not from a string. Something like this

```
ShapeDrawable drawable = new ShapeDrawable (new OvalShape());
```

There are other shapes and options, but you cannot parse a string.